# Two sets of colors/properties in powershell/cmd?

Tags: command-line, powershell

I am witnessing strange behavior of PowerShell.

Namely when I am running it from Start menu I am getting image on the left, but if I run it from the Run menu (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) I get the image on the right:

[image: Difference in color set and title]

The main difference seems to be that DarkMagenta and DarkYellow, which I use as default Background and Foreground colors, respectively, are different in each run and so are Window titles.

What are possible explanations and solutions for this? I am running Windows 7 SP1 64bit as Administrator.

EDIT: OK, I seem to revert the color set to norm by hand-typing numerical values into the "Selected Color" Box. But the question about different properties (as exemplified by Window Titles) still stands.

EDIT2: That's it, I figured it out: When I was running it from Start menu I was in fact clicking a shortcut with different properties then an actual application, when "Run" command ran application directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already discovered, the properties can be changed in the shortcuts, and you can copy and modify the shortcut.

The default settings are in the registry key `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]`, which can be exported to other user accounts or computers.

---

EDIT: Actually, that registry key is for CMD (I forgot that this question was regarding PowerShell while I was answering it).  I'm not sure where the corresponding one is for PowerShell.  It may be hardcoded into PowerShell.

The best way to change the PowerShell console properties is within your profile, as [this webpage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156814.aspx) shows (I don't think the font can be changed this way though).

Comment: @Zotov: Thanks.  I made a correction to my answer.