# Starting PowerShell 6.2.1 as administrator or user gives different fonts and position

Tags: powershell

When I open PowerShell from the Start menu as a user and as administrator, the console appears with different font sizes, colors, and position.

Starting as a user, I am not permitted to change the console properties. I want the user to be the same as the administrator console properties. How can I change the user console properties?

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
6.2.1
PS C:\> (Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Version
10.0.17763
```

This is not about the PowerShell profiles scripts. This is about the shortcut that starts PowerShell. When I try to change the console properties as a user, it reports that

```
Unable to modify the shortcut:
dir "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PowerShell\PowerShell 6 (x64).lnk"
Check to make sure it has not been deleted or renamed.
```

The file is clearly there.

```
PS C:\> dir "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PowerShell\PowerShell 6 (x64).lnk"

    Directory: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PowerShell

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2019-06-05    09:55           2010 PowerShell 6 (x64).lnk
```

How can I find the shortcut or way in which "Run as Administrator" starts PowerShell?

By getting $PID and Process Explorer, the only difference I see thus far is that the parent of the user pwsh.exe is explorer.exe. But the parent of the administrator pwsh.exe is RuntimeBroker.exe. I still do not know if there is a different shortcut (.lnk) for each.

Comment: These are defined in your PowerShell Profile, generally. It doesn't require admin rights to change your profile. This is just a file that is read each time you open PowerShell and can be unique to each account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two sets of colors/properties in powershell/cmd?](https://superuser.com/questions/339388/two-sets-of-colors-properties-in-powershell-cmd)

Comment: You will have to use your Administrator user to make the profiles identical.  [Windows PowerShell Profiles](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/csps/2010/06/06/windows-powershell-profiles/).  If you will indicate the profile path for each profile in question I can write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have been able to change the console settings (text color, background, position, etc.) by starting the shortcut with `Run as Administrator`. I this case, 6.2.1, on Windows 10, I could not.

What I did do was copy the shortcut, `"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PowerShell\PowerShell 6 (x64).lnk"` to the Desktop. From there I am able to change the console settings.